# Render Emoji HTML Entity stored in database in Django?

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views

I've stored the following HTML Entity (`&#x1f336;`) in varchar and is calling it from the database. And then using a for block in the HTML.

However, when the page is rendered, it is displayed as `&amp;#x1f336;` instead of the red pepper, I was hoping for.

Am wondering how the `amp;` got inserted.

Want `&#x1f336;` but got `&amp;#x1f336;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try marking the output as `|safe`.

Only do this if the database code is something you control and you know it is actually safe.

Read me here from the Django Docs:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe